# Ruby / Capybara - How to use a JQuery command in Capybara

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, capybara

I have the following JQuery script that are working in my Chrome console. However, it is not working when I use it in my Capybara test. What am I doing wrong?

**Script that works in my console**

```
$('#skuTabNavigation a[href="#tabImages"]').trigger('click');
```

**Script in my Capybara test. Did not work**

```
script = '$("#skuTabNavigation a[href="#tabImages"]").trigger("click")';
page.execute_script(script)
```

**Terminal MAC error**
 Failure/Error: page.execute_script(script)

```
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
   unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
     (Session info: headless chrome=73.0.3683.75)
     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628411 (3324f4c8be9ff2f70a05a30ebc72ffb013e1a71e),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to escape your quotes; you've got 2 sets of double quotes nested inside your capybara script example.

You might try escaping the quotes around tabImages:

```
script = "$('#skuTabNavigation a[href=\"#tabImages\"]').trigger('click')";
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answer me. Unfortunately, didn't work.. follow the new terminal error

Failure/Error: page.execute_script(script) -> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError: -> javascript error: $ is not defined

Comment: @DerekSanders This answer is 100% correct for the issue you originally posted. To diagnose your new issue you should run in non-headless mode and/or use `save_and_open_screenshot` to see what the page really looks like.  The second error is telling you that the $ method is not defined in the page, so either the page doesn't include JQuery or there's an error loading the page. Also note that by using `execute_script` to trigger a click you're bypassing the restrictions on what a user could do and your test potentially becomes worthless.

Comment: Hi, now worked. The problem was that my html code was inside an iframe. Thanks